# Programmatically add Purchase Order number

Tags: magento

In my Magento module Im creating orders programmatically. This process runs in the background so there is no possibility for customer interaction during this process. I want to use Magento's Purchase Order payment method, how do I insert Purchase order number programmatically? Don't know if my brain stopped working, but I cant seem to see a way to add that number. The only part of code with payment methods is this:

```
$shippingAddress->setPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
$quote->getPayment()->importData( array('method' => $paymentMethod));
```

How do I insert there the Purchase number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking in the Mage/Sales/model/Quote/Payment.php core code I found

@method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment setPoNumber(string $value)

that I think will help.

I added the setPoNumber('PO123456')  below in otherwise functional code where I think it goes.
I'll test later tonight.

public function PrepareConfirmOrder($customerID, $PartCart, $isHist) {

```
$customerObj=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerID);
$storeId = $customerObj->getStoreId();
$quoteObj=Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj);
$quoteObj->reserveOrderId();

$productModel=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
foreach($PartCart as $part) {
    foreach($part as $k=>$v) { $$k=$v; }
    $productObj=$productModel->load($PartId);
    $quoteItem=Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
    $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
    $quoteItem->setQty($qty);
    $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($UnitCost) ;
    $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
}
$quoteObj->collectTotals();
// Add shipping method to the quote
$quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
$quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)->save();

$quoteObj->save();

$quotePaymentObj=$quoteObj->getPayment();
//methods: authorizenet, paypal_express, googlecheckout, purchaseorder
$quotePaymentObj->setMethod('purchaseorder');
$quotePaymentObj->setPoNumber('PO1234567');
$quoteObj->setPayment($quotePaymentObj);
```

Comment: Thanks, tested it just now and it works. Dont know why I didnt notice that I can get payment object from quote, maybe then I would have gotten the right idea myself. I think I will modify my order creation process a little bit based on what you wrote, so thanks again.

Comment: Glad it works. I cannot take credit for the code though, I found in in various places on Magento forums and blogs